Custom Loss function Overfits to the Wrong Output but MSE Doesn't
I have a simple function that I want to approximate with a neural network:
N(1) = -1
N(2) = -1
N(3) = 1
N(4) = -1

Instead of using the MSE or cross-entropy losses, I wanted to experiment with a custom loss function:
it works like this:
if input == 3:
  loss = -1 * output
else:
  loss = 1 * output

If my network ends in a tanh activation, the neural network's loss minimizes when it approaches N. So the network should approach the weights to compute N.
But the network doesn't approach N. It approaches a function that outputs -1 for every input (even when the input is 3). Below is some sample code in pytorch to demonstrate:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Loss function
class CustomLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x, i):

        multiplier = -1 if i == 3 else 1

        return multiplier * x

# Network & Optimizer
net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1, 20),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(20, 20),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(20, 20),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(20, 1),
    nn.Tanh(),
)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
loss_function = CustomLoss()

# Training
for _i in range(100000):
    i = _i % 4 + 1
    input_value = torch.FloatTensor([i])
    output_value = net(input_value)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss_value = loss_function(output_value, i)
    loss_value.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print(i, output_value.item(), loss_value.item())

After running it for a minute, the output is as follows:
Input |         Output      |        Loss
1     | -0.9999958276748657 | -0.9999958276748657
2     | -0.9999961853027344 | -0.9999961853027344
3     | -0.9999962449073792 |  0.9999962449073792 <--- Loss can be minimized by making Output 1
4     | -0.9999962449073792 | -0.9999962449073792

I asked why the model isn't fitting in a previous question (on the AI stackexchange), but got the response that it was due to vanishing gradients because
$$
\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} tanh^{\prime}(x) = 0
$$
And once my model overfit to the case of outputting only -1, it would get trapped there since there is no gradient. But after testing this with MSE, the model correctly fit. Both of these loss functions don't solve the vanishing gradients problem. If a model gets overfit, there isn't much MSE can do to get it out of the zero gradient area.
To test this idea, I ran the model on my loss function for 1000 iterations (until it got overfit into the case of only outputting -1). Then I took this same overfit model, and ran it on MSE. After seeing the data, I was surprised to see that it was able to properly fit on MSE (even when overfit beforehand). So it seems I was wrong.
But my question is this: Why can the model break out of this zero gradient area on MSE when it can't for my loss function?
Thanks for any clarification on this.
EDIT:
You can test the MSE case using the following code after my above posted code:
print("MSE")
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

# Training
for _i in range(10000000):
    i = _i % 4 + 1
    input_value = torch.FloatTensor([i])
    output_value = net(input_value)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss_value = loss_function(output_value, torch.Tensor([-1 if i == 3 else 1]))
    loss_value.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print(i, output_value.item(), loss_value.item())

If you paste this code after my previously written code, it will run MSE on a model overfit to output -1 for every input.
EDIT 2:
For completeness, you can also test this with BCE by mapping -1 to 1 everywhere:
print("MSE")
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

# Training
for _i in range(10000000):
    i = _i % 4 + 1
    input_value = torch.FloatTensor([i])
    output_value = net(input_value)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss_value = loss_function((output_value + 1) / 2, torch.Tensor([0 if i == 3 else 1]))
    loss_value.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print(i, output_value.item(), loss_value.item())

And this should output the correct values as well.

I've replaced your custom loss with nn.MSELoss and it doesn't produce correct predictions for that, either. I don't know how you've used nn.BCELoss with this, because BCELoss requires the predicted values to be between 0 and 1, but tanh goes between -1 and 1. Can you [edit] to clarify? // Ultimately, I suspect the problem is that the custom loss is unbounded below; when considering all 4 data points, decreasing the loss on points other than 3 more than offsets increasing the loss for 3.

@Sycorax Thanks. I made a mistake when stating that I tested with BCE (I didn't actually, I'm not sure why I wrote that and will edit the question). Regarding MSE, my posted code doesn't work with it because i isn't the expected value (and isn't a tensor, as MSE requires). If you replace i in loss_function(output_value, i) with torch.Tensor([-1 if i == 3 else 1]), you should get the correct output.

Also I don't quite understand what you mean by unbounded in this case. Isn't MSE also unbounded?: $MSE(x, \bar{x}) = (x - \bar{x})^2$ doesn't have a maximum output. It could be that I don't know the definition of boundedness in this context.

MSE is minimized at $y - \hat y = 0$. Your loss can keep getting smaller as the output gets smaller. By contrast, MSE and BCE losses are minimized when the prediction matches the label. For any loss, there should be 0 gradient when the prediction matches the actual data, so that those weights stop updating, but that’s not the case for your custom loss function. Your loss has gradient 0 only when the output is 0, but this is actually not the desired result because for this data, none of the target values are 0.

I just started reading this question and I already struggle with the output and input. What are they?

@SextusEmpiricus in the code, input is i and output is output_value.

@Sycorax It confused me for a while. So we wish to estimate a function
$$y = f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \quad \text{if $x=1$}\
-1 & \quad \text{if $x=2$}\
1 & \quad \text{if $x=3$}\
-1 & \quad \text{if $x=4$}\
\end{cases}$$ where $y$ is output and $x$ is input. More intuitively some optimisation is made by comparing the estimated output with some known output $y$ versus $\hat{y}$. With the input, this is disguised, but we effectively have the loss function $L(y,\hat{y}) = -y \hat{y}$ instead of the square of residuals $L'(y,\hat{y}) = (y -\hat{y})^2$

The two loss functions look very much the same and do not differ a lot. We have $$L' = 1+ 2L+ \hat{y}^2$$. I imagine that the observed difference is due to a random instability in the fitting which tends to drive the linear predictors (before the tanh function) to infinitely high values and this happens faster than the correction can be learned to get the 3 input to negative infinity.

I wonder whether the model has the same tendency to fit badly when you make the influence of the 3 input stronger by having a larger amount of 3s in the training data.

Is there a online compiler somewhere that can run this code?

@SextusEmpiricus When making $N(1) = 1$ and $N(3) = -1$ (swapping the expected output of $1$ and $3$, the model fits correctly. I didn't include it in my post, but someone suggested that this was because i=1 is my first training input, so the model correctly fits for it then starts fitting for the other values. I think this is related to what you suggested with having more 3s in the data.

@AndrewBaker I currently don't have the ability to test this, and python code typically annoys me (when answering questions I often do this on the phone which doesn't run python, and online compilers are limited), but I imagine that you have a model where the fit for the '3' input is not managing to converge well because it is countered by the tendencies from the '1,2,4' inputs. And the successful fit with the sum of squared residuals loss might have been luck. When you repeat it several times, both loss functions might be equally successful/unsuccessful.

@AndrewBaker I think that swapping the labels so that $N(1)=1$ and $N(3)=-1$ (and keeping the rest the same) is easy to correctly fit because then the function is monotonic, whereas the original data requires the network to learn a function that has an increase and a decrease. If you wanted to test whether the first point seen by the model makes a difference, just start the range at 3. Using vanilla SGD in place of Adam would also lessen the effect of starting position and momentum on the results.

The problem is that the loss function only has 0 gradient when the neural network output is 0. This is not desirable! Instead, we want a loss function that has a 0 gradient when the output matches the target value. For MSE loss, the loss function achieves its minimum when the model output $\hat y$ equals the target value $y$ because this yields the result $(y - \hat y)^2 = 0$, whence the gradient is 0.
By contrast, the custom loss function can continue to become more negative (smaller) by making the output smaller for 1, 2, 4 and larger for 3. Moreover, the only time the gradient is 0 is when the output is 0, however 0 is not the output for any of the training data. This contradiction means that the model will always update its weights, even when the output is correct.

As an aside, the model is much more complex than is necessary.
The simplest possible $\tanh$ neural network for this data looks like a bump at 3 that decays to a horizontal asymptote everywhere else. With this in mind, we can easily sketch what a candidate solution looks like from first principles: rising on the left of 3, achiving a maximum at three, and declining on the right of 3.  Using $\tanh$ units, we know that this will look something like $w_1  \tanh(w_2x + b_1) + w_3  \tanh(w_4 x+b_2) + b_3$. Here's a sketch on wolfram alpha that looks basically like what we want.

So all we need to do is use an optimizer to find better weights and biases than the one in the cartoon. We can replace OP's network with this one
net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1, 2),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(2, 1),
    nn.Tanh(),
)

This 7-parameter model and MSE loss easily fits the data. (And you can reduce this even further if you do something like enforcing symmetry for the parameters.)

Thanks for the answer. I wanted to ask for clarification on two things: 1. does my loss function ever have gradient 0? The loss function is pretty much linear (either with slope -1 or 1), so the gradient should always be either of these, right? (before back propagation)


I'm assuming something like a cross entropy loss would work in my case, because this is a standard classification problem (although not binary from 0 to 1, it's binary from -1 to 1). Maybe I'll test it later. But from what I know, cross-entropy never has gradient 0 since its just the ln function (which has nonzero derivative everywhere).

So since cross-entropy and my custom losses both never have zero-gradient, why does cross-entropy perform well?

I address the first question in the answer. BCE has 0 gradient in the limit of the input tending to 0 or 1 (depending on the label).

Regarding my first question: Yeah, but I'm confused as to why the gradient is zero when the output is zero. Since my loss function is linear, shouldn't the gradient be either 1 or -1 when the output is zero?

Regarding the BCE gradients: But isn't BCE just -ln(x) or -ln(1 -x) depending on the label? The former has a derivative tending to $-\infty$ as $x \to 0$ and is equal to $-1$ when $x=1$, and the latter has a derivative tending to $+\infty$ as $x \to 1$ and is equal to $1$ when $x=0$? Am I wrong on what BCE is?

$$\log(1)=0$$..

Relating to the first paragraph "we want a loss function that has a 0 gradient when the output matches the target value." I believe that the problem is that this match never occurs and certain nodes in the network are being driven towards infinite values.

@SextusEmpiricus yes, that's what I said in the second paragraph

Oh, this all makes sense now. I was confusing target output with model output (i.e. $\hat{x}$ with $x$) in my previous comments. Thanks very much.
